# Java: Checking contents of char variable with if condition

Tags: java, variables, conditional-statements, char, if-statement

I have a char variable that is supposed to contain either a Y,y,n or N character, I want to test if it does not contain it, then display an error message and exit the program.

This is the code I am using;

```
    if (userDecision != 'Y' || userDecision != 'y' || userDecision != 'n' || userDecision != 'N')
        {
            System.out.println("Error: invalid input entered for the interstate question");
            System.exit(0);
        }
```

Irregardless of what is in the variable it always returns true and executes the command to exit the program, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

`||` means logical or. You want `&&` instead.

```
if (userDecision != 'Y' && userDecision != 'y' ...
```

---

`a || b` returns true if *either* a *or* b is true. Suppose the `userDecision` is `'Y'`. Then

- `userDecision != 'Y'` is false
- `userDecision != 'y'` is true
- `userDecision != 'N'` is true
- `userDecision != 'n'` is true

So together the condition is true and the if branch is executed.

OTOH, `a && b` returns true if *both* a *and* b are true, which is what you really need.

Answer (score 2):

Read the first part of the condition aloud: Is the choice different from `Y` or `y`? The problem is that any character is different either from `Y` or `y`. You’ve picked the wrong logical operator – if you want to be sure that user picked something else than those characters in the condition, you have to pick `&&`, logical and: Is the character different from `Y` *and* also different from `y` *and* etc.

Answer (score 2):

Change yoiur ORs to ANDs

Or you could use

```
(!(userDecision == 'Y' || userDecision == 'y' || userDecision == 'n' || userDecision == 'N'))
```

This

```
!(A OR B)
```

is equivelant to

```
!A AND !B
```

Have a look at [Boolean algebra](http://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

**De Morgans theorem**

```
NOT (P OR Q) = (NOT P) AND (NOT Q) 
NOT (P AND Q) = (NOT P) OR (NOT Q)
```

[DeMorgan's Theorem](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/HBASE/electronic/demorgan.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is "if this is not a or not b" this means it will always be true even if it is a or b. What you want to test for is "if this is not (a or b)" so:

```
if (! (userDecision == 'Y' || userDecision == 'y' || userDecision == 'n' || userDecision == 'N')) {
    System.out.println("Error: invalid input entered for the interstate question");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

If your code contains conditions like this that become long as many alternative chars must be tested for, you can use the switch construct, which makes this case easier to follow:

```
switch (userDecision) {
case 'y': /*fallthrough*/
case 'Y':
    // accepted
    break;
case 'n': /*fallthrough*/
case 'N':
    // rejected
    break;

default:
    System.out.println("Error: invalid input entered for the interstate question");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `&&` instead of `||`. You are asking whether "none" of those characters match, not simply whether any one of the four fail to match. (A value cannot simultaneously be Y, y, N, and n.)